# Creating flexible buttons with weight (chaining + spread)

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to make my buttons fill the space evenly, basically having each button fill one-third of the remaining space (there are three buttons).

According to [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html), I should chain the views (buttons) then spread them and at weights if necessary to fill the spaces. Then I should change the buttons vertical constraints to "Match Constraints". This however, causes the buttons to be uneven. I finally added `layout_constraintVertical_weight=""` to each `button` in the text of the XML file but to no avail. Using `android:layout_height` also does not work.

The XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#CCFFE5"
    android:weightSum="1"
    tools:context="com.example.shaynimex.boomnumber.HomeScreen">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="cursive"
        android:text="Boom Number"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1 PLAYER"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2 PLAYER"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="How to Play"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

It also currently looks like this (for the Pixel XL):

[image]

So how would I go about applying the weights to the buttons and making them fill the remaining space evenly?

Comment: sorry for not using ConstraintLayout. thank you for accepting my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not use ConstraintLayout because of the difficulty of weights.

[image]

if this what you want I just did this kind of code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="#CCFFE5">

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="cursive"
    android:text="Boom Number"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/textView"/>


  <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/button"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:text="1 PLAYER"
      android:textSize="30sp"
      android:textStyle="bold"/>
  </FrameLayout>

  <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/button3"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:text="2 PLAYER"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:textSize="30sp"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"      />
  </FrameLayout>

  <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/button4"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:text="How to Play"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:textSize="30sp"
      android:textStyle="bold"/>
  </FrameLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```